# How to add a change of color hover on ReorderableListView icons in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, widget, hover

[image]

I have this **ReorderableListView** in my app, and I would like that **when I hover** my mouse on the check-circle icons on the left, **they change color**,

Right now when I hover my mouse over it, nothing happens, they are not even clickable

Here is the part of the **ReorderableListView** code where I define icons and text of each item :

```
children: listeTaches.map((e) => ListTile(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      //leading: Icon(Icons.task),
                      leading: Icon(BeoticIcons.disc),
                      title: Text(e),
                      //trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      trailing: Icon(BeoticIcons.circle_check)
                    )).toList(),
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you:

I think is same as like our Icon Widget for eg.

```
Icon(Icons.add,color:Colors.red),
```

Just try your Icon like below

```
 Icon(BeoticIcons.circle_check,color:Colors.red),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the event and launch the desired code when it happens. For this, you will need a StatefulWidget and control the event that triggers it (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures).

Greetings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Mouse Region](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) to handle the hover interaction with your icon. If you wrap your icon widget with a mouse region then you just change the color in the onHover event. Something like this :

```
children: listeTaches.map((e) => ListTile(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  //leading: Icon(Icons.task),
                  leading: MouseRegion(
                              onHover: _updateIcon,
                              child:Icon(BeoticIcons.disc, color:my_color)),
                  title: Text(e),
                  //trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                  trailing: Icon(BeoticIcons.circle_check)
                )).toList(),
```

Then in the _updateIcon you could change a variable that the icon would use as the color

```
final my_color = Colors.grey; //declare before with the default color of your icon
   
      _updateIcon(){
      setState(() {
        my_color = Colors.red;
      });
}
```

Hope i could help :)

Comment: Thanks man, I tried it, it works... but only one time, when I hover it changes the color but the new color stay and it changes the color of each icons of the list instead of only the one selected, and when I hover again it duplicates the list elements, and all this indefinitely.

Comment: I try using the onEnter and onExit attributes instead of onHover so that the color go back to the old one after I leave the icon with my mouse, but it still work one time, after I re-hover the icon the duplicate indefinitely (at each new hover) and don't change color.

Comment: i was editing my answer to tell you to use the onEnter and onExit events when i got the notification of your second comment hahah. I'll do some more thinking and research because i just can't see right now why this is happening, maybe it has something to do with the function usage. Try to make the changes directly after the onEnter event and tell us if it changes something.

Comment: Could you provide some code of the data insertion on the list?

Comment: My list was fetching data from a webservice and I think it's calling the data at each event and feeding the list each time. I tried with static data and there is not this duplication problem. The problem that is still present with static data is that when I hover the icon of one element of the list, all the corresponding icons of the other elements change color.

Comment: Nice that you solved the duplication problem, congrats. Yeah i see the problem with my answer on the changing of color, it doesn't use a index to set which listTile the change has to happen. You could pass the index to the original function of my answer and then change only the icon that you are hovering.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help. Well, I might have identified the problem but as for now I have no clue how to resolve it. For my other issue, your solution with the index makes a lot of sense I'm trying to look how to implement it but I have to admit than I'm kind of stuck right now. If you have any example for implementing the index I will take it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237565/discussion-between-luan-silva-and-js1).